# How to use a boolean field in mapserver expression?

Tags: mapserver

I have the following class where `correctie` is a `Boolean` field.

```
CLASS
  NAME "vestiging (correctie)"

  EXPRESSION (correctie = TRUE)

  STYLE
    MINSCALEDENOM  100
    MAXSCALEDENOM  19001

    SYMBOL         "dashstip"
    SIZE           20
    ANTIALIAS      true
  END
END
```

The `EXPRESSION` part does not work

Comment: I think this will depend on what the data source is, ie: is it shapefiles?, ogr connection?, a postgis connection?, something else?

Comment: @StephenWoodbridge it is a postgis connection. I expected that that would not matter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is connection specific because it has to do with how each connection represents: `true|false`.

As you can see the postgis connection uses `'t'|'f'`, 
but others might use `0|1`.

One trick I have used in the past is to set the field in question to be used temporarily as the label then look on the image and see what values are being rendered in the labels using that field, then you can adjust the mapfile appropriately.

Comment: that's a nice debug tip! Do you have more of these tips? And what replacement of mapserver do you recommend? mapserver does the job wel but fees a bit od and old :)

Comment: Mapserver is mature not old ;) It is still under active development and is one of the faster and most general purpose tools around for rendering maps. If you want a tiled solution you can combine it with mapcache to generate and manage multiple tile caches. Open specific questions and your will get answers.

Answer (score 2):

For a boolean field out of a postgis connection you need:

```
EXPRESSION ('[correctie]' = 't')
```

Comment: If use use CLASSITEM 'correctie' then you can use EXPRESSION 't' or EXPRESSION 'f' in the CLASS.